# Problem having an aligned column using multicol

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate, two-column, multicol

I'm having problems getting a good-looking column. (The text is in Danish.) What can I do to get them aligned?

```
\section{Teknologianalyse}
\subsection{Teknik}
\begin{multicols}{2}
        \noindent{}\textbf{De maskiner som vi brugte under arbejdsprocessen:}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item En mekanisk automatisk metalsav.
        \item Søljebord.
        \item Svejsebord/maskine.
        \item Sav.
        \item Fil.
    \item Skruetvinge.
    \end{enumerate}
\columnbreak
    \textbf{Krav til arbejderne som betjener maskinerne:}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item At de har hænder, øjne og fødder.
        \item At de kan benytte en mekanisk automatisk sav.
        \item At de kan svejse.
        \item At de kan benytte en sav.
        \item At de kan benytte en fil. 
        \item At de kan benytte en skruetvinge.
        \item At de kan benytte et søljebord.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

[image: output]

Comment: could you include the packages and eventual rules you are using?

Comment: Use `paracol` instead of `multicol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
...
\vfill
\columnbreak
...
```

and if you want it horizontally aligned by the numbers use a longtable